# Why autowiring spring repositories doesn't work?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a controller where I autowire repository:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/account")
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepo;

//methods

}
```

My repository extends CrudRepository

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Integer> {

    Account findOne(int primaryKey);
}
```

I use xml to configure my project. Here it is:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.library.repositories"
        entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManager"></jpa:repositories>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.library.entities" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop> -->
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>
```

Why it doesn't work? The error I receive is that AccountController cannot autowire bean AccountRepository.

EDIT
I've refactored my configuration to annotation based and everything works. In my XML version I probably didn't scan some classes and it resulted with error.

Comment: share complete stack trace

Comment: is the repository's package coverd by your component-scan setting ?

Answer (score 2):

May be you need to have **@EnableJpaRepositories** annotation on a configuration class with **@Configuration** annotation instead of Controller class.

Also, make sure your Configuration classes are under a scanned package.

Comment: And to chime in here :-) XML is no longer needed anywhere in a spring project (Finally!). I recently did one which was 100% XML free. Even the web.xml file is no longer needed and this was on a WebSphere server.